# display a PDF with a blob from a base64 string

Tags: javascript, html, django, pdf, display

I want to display a pdf on a browser. The pdf content is downloaded fom an azure blob storage and then encoded in base64 string. Then I transfer this content to the html template to decode and display it. Below is my first attempt with the views.py from my django app that works however only for files smaller than 2MB.

##### views.py

```
def displayFILE(request, file_id):

    context = initialize_context(request)

    file = UploadFilesAAD.objects.get(pk=file_id)
    filename = file.Filename
    
    file_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
    url = file.Url
    blob_name = url.split("/")[-1]
    blob_content = download_from_blob(blob_name)
    encodedstring = base64.b64encode(blob_content.readall())
    content = blob_content.readall()
    
    context["content"] = str(content)
    context["encodedstring"] = str(encodedstring)[1:].replace("'","")
    
    return render(request, 'archivage/displayFILE.html', context)
```

##### html

```
{% load static %}

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>

    <object>
        <embed id="pdfID" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" src="data:application/pdf;base64,{{ encodedstring }}" />
    </object>

</body>
</html>
```

I do not want limitation on the file size, so I try to write with Javascript. Firts I convert string encoded to Blob. Then I generate the temporary DOM String base on Blob. Finally, I display it. My code doesn't work but I do not get what is wrong. I am learning Javascript so I am probably missing something.

##### the new html

```
{% load static %}

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
    {{ encodedstring | json_script:'mydata' }} 

    <div id="pdf"></div>

    <script>
        const mydata = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('mydata').textContent);

        const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType='', sliceSize=512) => {
        const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
        const byteArrays = [];

        for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
            const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

            const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
            for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
            byteArrays.push(byteArray);
        }

        const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
        return blob;
        }
        
        const contentType = 'application/pdf';
        const blob = b64toBlob(mydata, contentType);
        var temp_url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        const target = document.querySelector('pdf');

        target.innerHTML = <iframe src='${temp_url}' type="application/pdf"></iframe>;
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: @KJ Thank you for your answer, however I do not want to download it loacally on the computer to display it. It is possible to do it how I want ? I do not get what is missing in my code. Another question. Can I display the content without encode it in base64 ? if you see my view in django, I get the content of the pdf from the blob storage.

Comment: @KJ sorry I am quite a newbee in the web develepment. What I meant, it that I would not want that when the user ask to view a pdf from a list of pdf store in an azure blob storage, that the pdf is downloaded in C disk zo display it. I would like something like that use the content of the file that is store in the memory if it is possible.

like : `<embed id="pdfID" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" src="data:application/pdf;base64,{{ encodedstring }}" />`

Yes, I did two buttons, on that download the file and another to display. The django view to display it works perfectly.